# Connecting Node-Red to Mariadb within Docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, mariadb, node-red

Evening all,

Setting up a fairly straightforward Mosquitto -> Node-Red -> Mariadb deployment, from docker-compose. Compose file as below:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
        mqtt:
                container_name: mosquitto
                image: eclipse-mosquitto:latest
                restart: always
                ports: 
                    - "1883:1883"
                volumes:
                        - ./mosquitto.conf:/mosquitto/config/mosquitto.conf
                        - /mosquitto/data
                        - /mosquitto/log

        nodered:
                container_name: node-red
                image: nodered/node-red:latest
                restart: always
                ports: 
                    - "1880:1880"
                volumes:
                        - node_red_user_data:/data
                links:
                        - "mariadb:mariadb"

        mariadb:
                container_name: mariadb
                image: mariadb:latest
                restart: always
                command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
                ports: 
                    - "3306:3306"
                    - "33060:33060"
                environment:
                        - MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD=yes
                        - MYSQL_DATABASE=test
                        - MYSQL_USER=testuser
                        - MYSQL_PASSWORD=password

                volumes:
                        - mariadb_data_container:/var/lib/mysql

volumes:
        mariadb_data_container:
        node_red_user_data:
        mosquitto_persistence:


networks:
        default:
                name: primary
```

Mosquitto to Node-Red is working well enough, and I've set up the database and table in mariadb, but I'm not having any luck getting Node-Red to talk to Maria. Getting this error thrown back at me.

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306
```

The Node-red node in question is as follows:

```
[{"id":"d93d7d2b.ee27f","type":"mysql","z":"ec0540ab.8b4e2","mydb":"68416de0.8f91a4","name":"XDK Environmental Data","x":750,"y":260,"wires":[["d0d7439f.9b88d"]]},{"id":"68416de0.8f91a4","type":"MySQLdatabase","z":"","name":"Write to mariadb","host":"localhost","port":"3306","db":"XDK_FEM","tz":""}
```

Full Node-red flow here, in case that's in some way useful.

```
[{"id":"ec0540ab.8b4e2","type":"tab","label":"MQTT_MYSQL_write","disabled":false,"info":""},{"id":"772011e7.51dd4","type":"mqtt in","z":"ec0540ab.8b4e2","name":"XDK1_Output","topic":"BCDS/XDK110/example/out","qos":"2","datatype":"utf8","broker":"ac9b691.6c35998","x":90,"y":260,"wires":[["f7d34d6b.63919","8336338b.e648c"]]},{"id":"d0d7439f.9b88d","type":"debug","z":"ec0540ab.8b4e2","name":"","active":true,"tosidebar":true,"console":false,"tostatus":false,"complete":"true","targetType":"full","statusVal":"","statusType":"auto","x":990,"y":260,"wires":[]},{"id":"d79d4ae0.fcf958","type":"function","z":"ec0540ab.8b4e2","name":"Create query in topic","func":"var out = \"INSERT INTO XDK1_raw (timestamp,message)\"\nout = out + \"VALUES ('\" + new Date().toISOString() + \"','\" \nout = out + msg.payload + \"');\"\nmsg.topic=out;\n\nreturn msg;","outputs":1,"noerr":0,"initialize":"","finalize":"","x":500,"y":260,"wires":[["d93d7d2b.ee27f"]]},{"id":"9b43a338.781","type":"comment","z":"ec0540ab.8b4e2","name":"Log everything","info":"","x":100,"y":200,"wires":[]},{"id":"d93d7d2b.ee27f","type":"mysql","z":"ec0540ab.8b4e2","mydb":"68416de0.8f91a4","name":"XDK Environmental Data","x":750,"y":260,"wires":[["d0d7439f.9b88d"]]},{"id":"f7d34d6b.63919","type":"debug","z":"ec0540ab.8b4e2","name":"","active":false,"tosidebar":true,"console":false,"tostatus":false,"complete":"payload","targetType":"msg","statusVal":"","statusType":"auto","x":310,"y":180,"wires":[]},{"id":"8336338b.e648c","type":"json","z":"ec0540ab.8b4e2","name":"","property":"payload","action":"str","pretty":true,"x":270,"y":300,"wires":[["cbee55ed.b7a668","d79d4ae0.fcf958"]]},{"id":"cbee55ed.b7a668","type":"debug","z":"ec0540ab.8b4e2","name":"","active":false,"tosidebar":true,"console":false,"tostatus":false,"complete":"false","statusVal":"","statusType":"auto","x":480,"y":380,"wires":[]},{"id":"ac9b691.6c35998","type":"mqtt-broker","z":"","name":"XDK_Mosquitto","broker":"192.168.1.115","port":"1883","clientid":"","usetls":false,"compatmode":false,"keepalive":"60","cleansession":true,"birthTopic":"","birthQos":"0","birthPayload":"","closeTopic":"","closeQos":"0","closePayload":"","willTopic":"","willQos":"0","willPayload":""},{"id":"68416de0.8f91a4","type":"MySQLdatabase","z":"","name":"Write to mariadb","host":"localhost","port":"3306","db":"XDK_FEM","tz":""}]
```

I've tried various combinations of ports and configs, and after digging myself deeper into a hole I've just reset everything to start from scratch.

Any insight gratefully received!

**EDIT**

I realise this isn't a very helpful update for anyone facing the same image, but in the end I deleted the container and started again from the docker-compose and it worked. Lord only knows. Working theory is that before hitting on the right answer (using 'mariadb' instead of 'localhost') I broke something trying a wrong answer.

Answer (score 2):

The important thing to remember is that each container has it's own loopback device (lo, 127.0.0.1) and the host for the containers has it's own as well and they are all totally separate.

So you can not reference the MariaDB container as `127.0.0.1` from the Node-RED container as that address points to the Node-RED container.

You need to use the hostname `mariadb` not `127.0.0.1` when entering the details or the mariadb config node.

Comment: I knew it was something along those lines! Although possibly just the first of my problems, as it's now changed to


`Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 172.18.0.2:3306`